# Password protecting endeca JSP reference application

Tags: endeca

We have a requirement to password protect access to the Endeca JSP reference application. I have already enabled SSL but what is a secure way to add password protection?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to secure a J2EE application. By enabling SSL I assume you've modified the `web.xml` in the `[TOOLS_AND_FRAMEWORK_HOME]\11.1.0\reference\endeca_jspref\WEB-INF` folder.

To add basic authentication into the J2EE application you need to create a couple of forms and modify the `web.xml` again. A complete example of doing this can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html).

Comment: dear downvoter, if there is anything wrong with this approach, requiring a down vote, please let me know so I can improve it.